# java pgm 2 jpeg/png

Tags: java, png, jpeg, jai, pgm

I have an int array containing gray scale values from 0-254, i also have the x and y size of the image. It is an easy thing to create an pgm image, but i want to display it in a jsp, so i need somehow to convert it to a jpeg or png image. 
If you suggest jai, than please tell me at which classes to look, or how to actually do it in jai.
Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe skip the PGM entirely?

```
int[] myImage = getGreyscaleIntArray();

BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
WritableRaster raster = im.getRaster();
for(int h=0;h<height;h++)
{
    for(int w=0;w<width;w++)
    {
        raster.setSample(w,h,0, myImage[h * width + w]); 
    }
}

ByteArrayOutputStream myJpg = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(im, "jpg", myJpg);
```

uses the [JAI ImageIO api](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/index.html), specifically the [ImageIO utility class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

WriteableRaster sample from [the Java Image Processing cookbook](http://www.lac.inpe.br/~rafael.santos/JIPCookbook/1200-create-gl.jsp#imageanddatamanipulationcreatinggraylevelimageswithoutusingjai)

Comment: This was the first thing a thought about. But it doesnt work. 

Try reading a pgm file. ImageIO.read() will always return null if it's pgm format.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) works well for converting images and [Jmagick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/) provides an interface to call directly from java programs.

Comment: I would have to install ImageMagick. I don't want to do that, since i wouldn't be able to deploy the app on any server running tomcat.